# iOS Facebook Open Graph Get Link For Post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the link to a Facebook Page's Post.  However, links only show up under the actions field, and for every like, comment, or share, it lists the link again.  I use:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/v2.3/116178611870507/feed?limit=20" parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id, actions, message, full_picture" forKey:@"fields"]]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
```

The result shows up in console as

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            actions =             (
                                {
                    link = "https://www.facebook.com/116178611870507/posts/534581860030178";
                    name = Comment;
                },
                                {
                    link = "https://www.facebook.com/116178611870507/posts/534581860030178";
                    name = Like;
                },
                                {
                    link = "https://www.facebook.com/116178611870507/posts/534581860030178";
                    name = Share;
                }
            );
```

I guess my question would be, how can I access the link in there, but limit to only pulling it one time instead of for every like share or comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
NSMutableArray *link = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *dataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[yourFacebookResult objectForKey:@"data"]];

    for (int i=0; i < dataArr.count; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < [[[dataArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"actions"] count]; j++) {
            [link addObject:[[[[dataArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"actions"] objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"link"]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Your all link -> %@",link);
```